# Xamarin IOS: Is there a file picker picker

Tags: xamarin, icloud, filepicker

I am looking for a File Picker library using iCloud for Xamarin Form for iOS. Currently I am using [FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows](https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows/blob/master/README.md) for Xamarin Form project. It will show the file picker on android application but when running on iOS, there is an error message :

> This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly.  You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.

Even though the package works, but still not working well.

Comment: Have you seen that plugin's issue [here](https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows/issues/3#issuecomment-243350984)? Looks like you have to manually add the DLL. There is also a pull request [here](https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows/pull/11) where the `null` filename issue was apparently fixed.

Comment: Do you mean i have to download the whole library and compile it then copy the dll ..

Comment: I have never used that plugin so I am not sure either. Might try to test it out today if I have time and will get back to you if I get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [the document picker in Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_the_document_picker/)? Might not be suitable for all purposes, but worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,
You have to add the dll references of the plugin Picker manually and delete the package reference.
here the steps

1.Delete the reference to the FilePicker package in the package folder of the iOS project:
[image]

2. Add the two dlls to the references of the iOS project.

   - Right click to your project -> Edit References
     [image]
   - On the .Net Assembly tab add the references to the two dlls:

     - YourProjectDirectory/packages/Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker.1.2.1/lib/MonoTouch10/Plugin.FilePicker.dll
     - YourProjectDirectory/packages/Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker.1.2.1/lib/MonoTouch10/Plugin.FilePicker.Abstractions.dll

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're using the old FilePicker project from Studyxnet that seems to not being maintained anymore. There is a well maintailed FilePicker plugin in this Github repository:
https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows
(note: I'm one of the contributors).

The error you mentioned is fixed in the latest NuGet package, and is also mentioned on the project's README.md. Background is that the Xamarin Plugins all use the same or similar mechanism where the Abstractions project defines an interface (e.g. IFilePicker), and the platform dependent implementation is in a different assembly that is only into the .apk or .ipa based on the platform (Android, iOS, etc.).